# Using cumcount() with dups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df that looks like this:

```
ID Component IDDate                   EmployeeID CreateUserID
24 1         2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
24 2         2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
24 3         2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
25 1         2017-09-12 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
25 3         2017-09-12 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
26 8         2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
26 11        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
26 12        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
26 23        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
27 21        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
27 22        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
27 23        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior
28 15        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
28 16        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
28 19        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
28 25        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
28 26        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde
```

I'm trying to use cumcount to create a variable that holds the order of observations for each ID/EmployeeID combo. I haven't been able to get the count to apply at the level I want, but have tried variations on `cumcount()` that aren't getting me quite to where I want to be, like:

```
df['seq'] = df.groupby(['EmployeeID', 'ID', 'Date']).cumcount().add(1)

df['seq'] = df.groupby(['EmployeeID', 'Date']).cumcount().add(1)

df['seq'] = df.groupby(['EmployeeID', 'ID']).cumcount().add(1)
```

Ideally, my output looks like this:

```
ID Component IDDate                   EmployeeID CreateUserID seq
24 1         2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        1
24 2         2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        1
24 3         2017-09-11 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        1
25 1         2017-09-12 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        2
25 3         2017-09-12 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        2
26 8         2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        1
26 11        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        1
26 12        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        1
26 23        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        1
27 21        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        3
27 22        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        3
27 23        2017-09-16 00:00:00.000  0907036    Afior        3
28 15        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        2
28 16        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        2
28 19        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        2
28 25        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        2
28 26        2017-10-16 00:00:00.000  1013842    JHyde        2
```

Is there a way to deal with dups that would get me to this output? Would it be better to make the df wide first and then apply `cumcount()`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is convert to categorical data and get the `codes`

```
df[['IDDate','EmployeeID']].apply(tuple,1).groupby(df['CreateUserID']).apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes+1)
Out[8]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, essentially grouping just by `EmployeeID`, then checking if the `ID` changes from one row to the next, and returning the `cumsum` of that (this is based on your attempts and your desired output).

```
df['seq'] = df.groupby('EmployeeID')['ID'].transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())

>>> df
    ID  Component                   IDDate  EmployeeID CreateUserID  seq
0   24          1  2017-09-11 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    1
1   24          2  2017-09-11 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    1
2   24          3  2017-09-11 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    1
3   25          1  2017-09-12 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    2
4   25          3  2017-09-12 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    2
5   26          8  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    1
6   26         11  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    1
7   26         12  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    1
8   26         23  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    1
9   27         21  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    3
10  27         22  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    3
11  27         23  2017-09-16 00:00:00.000      907036        Afior    3
12  28         15  2017-10-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    2
13  28         16  2017-10-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    2
14  28         19  2017-10-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    2
15  28         25  2017-10-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    2
16  28         26  2017-10-16 00:00:00.000     1013842        JHyde    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to groupby EmployeeID and then do a dense rank on the Date:

```
In [187]: df.groupby("EmployeeID")["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense')).astype(int)
Out[187]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

This will rank by value and not by first-seen, although if Date is sorted as in your example it won't matter.